# How to synchronize threads in java

Tags: java, thread-safety

I need to register the order of each customer
The waiter can only deliver orders after write down all requests of your customers.
Customer must wait until the request is delivered

I can not synchronize the client actions with the waiter

I need synchronize each action from my objects Customer and Waiter
Customer has 1 order
Waiter has N customers

The sequence of actions to be synchronized was implemented in the "run" method of each thread

```
package room;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Customer extends Thread {

    private Random random;
    private int id;
    private static int ID;
    private Order order;
    private Waiter waiter;

    public Customer(Waiter garcom) {
        this.random = new Random();
        this.id = ID + 1;
        Customer.ID++;
        this.waiter = garcom;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        orderRequest();
        waitOrder();
        receiveRequest();
        consumer();
    }

    public synchronized void orderRequest() {
        synchronized (this.order) {

            int r = random.nextInt(3);
            switch (r) {
                case 0:
                    this.order.setOrder("Food");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.order.setOrder("Drink");
                    break;
                default:
                    this.order.setOrder("Help");
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println(this.toString() + " request " + this.order.getOrder() + "to " + this.waiter.toString());

              this.order.notify();

            try {
                this.order.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

    public synchronized void receiveRequest() {

        synchronized (this.order) {

            this.order.notify();

            try {
                this.order.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            System.out.println(this + " has received " + this.order + " from " + this.waiter);
        }
    }

    private void waitOrder() {
        synchronized (this.order) {

            System.out.println(this + " consumer " + this.order);

            this.order.notify();

            try {
                this.order.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

    public synchronized void consumer() {

        synchronized (this.order) {

            System.out.println(this + " was consumed " + this.order);

            this.order.notify();

            try {
                this.order.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer: " + id;
    }
}

package room;

public class Order {

    private int orderNumber;
    private static int ORDER_NUMBER = 0;
    private Customer customer;
    private String order;

    public Order(Customer c) {
        this.customer = c;
        this.orderNumber = ORDER_NUMBER + 1;
        this.customer.setOrder(this);
        Order.ORDER_NUMBER++;

    }

    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public int getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }


    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order: " + order + " Nº " + orderNumber;
    }

}

package room;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Waiter extends Thread {

    private Saloon saloon;
    private int id;
    private static int ID = 0;
    private List<Order> orders;

    public Waiter(Saloon bar) {
        this.saloon = bar;
        this.id = ID + 1;
        Waiter.ID++;
        this.orders = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (saloon.isOpen()) {

            registerOrder();
            deliveryRequest();

            saloon.round();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void registerOrder() {

        for (Order order : orders) {

            synchronized (order) {

                order.notify();

                try {
                    order.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                System.out.println(this.toString() + " "
                        + "record " + order.toString()
                        + " to " + order.getCustomer());

            }
        }

    }

    public synchronized void deliveryRequest() {

        for (Order order : orders) {

            synchronized (order) {

                order.notify();

                try {
                    order.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Waiter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                System.out.println(this.toString() + " "
                        + "delivered " + order.toString()
                        + " to " + order.getCustomer());

            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void recordOrder(Order order) {

        synchronized (orders) {
            this.orders.add(order);
        }
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public Saloon getSaloon() {
        return saloon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Waiter: " + id;
    }
}

package room;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Saloon {

    private int maxRound;
    private int numGarcons;
    private volatile int round;
    private int capacity;
    private int customerCount;
    private final List<Waiter> waiters;

    public Saloon() {
        this.waiters = new ArrayList<>();
        this.round = 1;
    }

    public Saloon(int customerCount, int waiterCount,
            int capacity, int rounds) {
        this();

        this.numGarcons = waiterCount;
        this.customerCount = customerCount;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.maxRound = rounds;

    }

    /**
     *  Should it be call each round
     */
    public void openBar() {

        this.capacity = this.customerCount / this.capacity;
        System.out.println("Round " + this.round);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.numGarcons; i++) {

            //Create a waiter
            Waiter g = new Waiter(this);

            for (int j = 0; j < this.capacity; j++) {
                //create customer
                Customer c = new Customer(g);
                //an order
                Order p = new Order(c);
                //register order
                g.recordOrder(p);
                //call thread client
                c.start();
            }
            //waiter serves one client at a time
            g.start();

            this.waiters.add(g);
        }

    }

    public boolean isOpen() {

        if (this.round < this.maxRound) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void round() {
        this.round++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So for starters it looks like order is never set for the waiter. You created an order for the customer and set it in the order list but when do you pass that to the waiter?

Comment: Just so you know I am looking over the entire code though and working a fix

Comment: This is quite similar to [The Sleeping Barber problem](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/Blitz/OSProject/p3/SleepingBarberProblem.pdf), [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem). Analogy is that Waiter is similar to the barber and Customer task is changed from Haircut to Food order. There are minor differences but you can start [here](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/kerola/rio/ohjeet/Java/semaphores/s06e-huhtamaki-merikanto-nevalainen/SleepingBarber.java).

Comment: And I found a suitable response... man that was fun though it's been awhile I dealt with that problem myself.

Comment: Maxs728 you right, my problem is exactly this, i can't call waiter after that all customers have asked

Answer (score 0):

Okay I must say I enjoyed the challenge... But I have figured this out. I should note that I attempted your original maxRounds and though it works there is a bug where 1 extra customer can make it through the queue. **NOTE:** I am do not claim this is the absolute best way to do this... nor necessarily the most elegant but it should point you towards the right direction.

I would suggest reading about [BlockingQueues](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html) and classes the extend it.

Main call to the saloon:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Saloon saloon = new Saloon(100, 4, 50);
  saloon.openBar();
}
```

Saloon Class:

```
package room;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Saloon {

    private volatile static int round;
    private static int maxRound;
    private int numWaiters;
    private final List<Waiter> waiters;
    private int customerMax; // current implementation doesn't need this but you could if you wanted
    private volatile static boolean isOpen;
    private OrderQueue<Order> orderQueue; // This is the creation of the queue

    public Saloon() {
        this.waiters = new ArrayList<>();
        Saloon.round = 1;
    }

    public Saloon(int customerMax, int numWaiters, int maxRounds) {
        this();
        this.customerMax = customerMax;
        this.numWaiters = numWaiters;
        this.orderQueue = new OrderQueue<Order>(numWaiters);
        Saloon.maxRound = maxRounds;
    }

    /**
     *  Should it be call each round
     */
    public void openBar() {
        System.out.println("Round " + round);
        isOpen = true;
        // Create all waiters at once outside the loop
        for (int i = 0; i < this.numWaiters; i++) {
            waiters.add(new Waiter(i + 1, orderQueue));
            waiters.get(i).start();
        }
        int customersServed = 1; // Generating the id number here is a better choice IMO
        while(isOpen) {
            for (Waiter waiter : waiters) {
                if (round >= maxRound) {
                    closeBar();
                }
                if (waiter.isAvailable() && !waiter.isClockedOut()) {
                    // create customer
                    Customer customer = new Customer(customersServed++, waiter, orderQueue);
                    customer.start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A simple implementation to close the bar
     */
    public void closeBar() {
        isOpen = false; // ends the loop
        int waitersFinished = 0; // used to check if all waiters stopped serving
        while (waitersFinished < numWaiters) {
            for (Waiter waiter : waiters) {
                if (waiter.isAvailable()) {
                    synchronized (orderQueue) {
                        // if nothing is currently in the queue for the waiters
                        if (orderQueue.isEmpty()) {
                            orderQueue.done(); // close the queue
                            orderQueue.notify(); // notify the queue
                        }
                        waiter.clockOut(); // clockout the waiter could use better implementation
                        waitersFinished++; // increment waiters finished
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isOpen() {
        return isOpen;
    }

    // I would not recommend using this... this is the source of the glitch
    public synchronized static void round() {
        if (round <= maxRound) { // only if reached maxRounds
            System.out.println("Round " + round);
            round++;
        }
    }
}
```

OrderQueue Class:

```
package room;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

/**
 * 
 * Note I did not create this.. tomasb did and I implemented it.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class OrderQueue<T> extends ArrayBlockingQueue<T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean done = false;

    /**
     * creates an order queue with a max capacity.. orders that can be concurrently handled
     * @param capacity
     */
    public OrderQueue(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

    /**
     * closes the while loop ending this orderqueue
     */
    public void done() {
        done = true;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return done;
    }

    /**
     * May return null if producer ends the production after consumer has
     * entered the element-await state.
     */
    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        T el;
        while ((el = super.poll()) == null && !done) {
            synchronized (this) {
                wait();
            }
        }

        return el;
    }
}
```

Order Class:

```
package room;

public class Order {

    private int orderNumber;
    private static int ORDER_NUMBER = 0;
    private String order;

    public Order(int orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = ORDER_NUMBER + 1;
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public int getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order: " + order + " Nº " + orderNumber;
    }
}
```

Customer Class:

```
package room;

import java.util.Random;

public class Customer extends Thread {

    private int id;
    private int orderNumber = 1;
    private Order order;
    private Waiter waiter;
    private OrderQueue<Order> orderQueue; // This provides an esay way to pass objects

    public Customer(int id, Waiter waiter, OrderQueue<Order> orderQueue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.waiter = waiter;
        this.orderQueue = orderQueue;
        waiter.addCustomer(this);
        System.out.println("Customer: " + id + " sat at a table!");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Notice that wait has been removed. The orderQueue takes care of this.
        orderRequest();
        receiveRequest();
        consumer();
        System.out.println("Customer: " + id + " has left satisfied!");
    }

    public void orderRequest() {
        // none of thie should be synchronized as it is local
        order = new Order(orderNumber++);

        Random random = new Random();
        int r = random.nextInt(3);
        switch (r) {
        case 0:
            order.setOrder("Food");
            break;
        case 1:
            order.setOrder("Drink");
            break;
        default:
            order.setOrder("Help");
            break;
        }

        System.out.println(this.toString() + " request " + order.getOrder() + " to " + this.waiter.toString());

        // only the call to the orderqueue is synchronized
        try {
            synchronized (orderQueue) {
                orderQueue.put(order);
                orderQueue.notify();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void receiveRequest() {
        System.out.println(this + " has received " + this.order + " from " + this.waiter);
    }

    public void consumer() {
        System.out.println(this + " was consumed " + this.order);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer: " + id;
    }
}
```

And finally the Waiter Class:

```
package room;

public class Waiter extends Thread {

    private int id;
    private Order custOrder;
    private Customer customer;
    private volatile boolean isAvailable;
    private volatile boolean clockOut;
    private OrderQueue<Order> orderQueue; // The queue again

    public Waiter(int id, OrderQueue<Order> orderQueue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.orderQueue = orderQueue;
        System.out.println("Waiter " + id + " is ready to serve!");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        isAvailable = true;
        while (!orderQueue.isDone() && !clockOut) {
            if (isAvailable) { // this waiter is ready for a task
                registerOrder();
                isAvailable = false;
                synchronized (orderQueue) { // Synchronize this to the queue to prevent worse glitches
                    Saloon.round();
                }
                if (custOrder != null) { // error checking
                    System.out.println(this.toString() + " record " + custOrder.toString() + " to " + customer);
                    deliveryRequest();
                } else {
                    isAvailable = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void registerOrder() {
        try {
            custOrder = orderQueue.take(); // this is how you pull the order
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            System.out.println(true);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void deliveryRequest() {
        System.out.println(this.toString() + " " + "delivered " + custOrder.toString() + " to " + customer);
        isAvailable = true;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) { // a easy way to add customers to the waiter after creation
        this.customer = customer;
        isAvailable = false;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return custOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Waiter: " + id;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return isAvailable;
    }

    public void clockOut() {
        clockOut = true;
    }

    public boolean isClockedOut() {
        return clockOut;
    }
}
```

Comment: My dear, first i would like to thank you and say it that I already knew about this class  BlockingQueues, but for this problem the using this class was restricted.
I wanna make this without class ArrayBlockingQueue

Comment: I have to say that not are synchronized, the round printing. It's repeating the round without need and printing the same round before the round finish

Another thing, it's generate deadlock when i try this
new Saloon(3, 1, 3);

Comment: I will have to check on what you are talking about. I wasn't getting those errors. If you don't mind what version of Java are you developing with? I am currently developing on 8

Comment: Yes, I'm developing on Java 8

Comment: each call to set /get use getter  isAvailable should be synchronized same for clockOut 
READ - MODIFY - WRITE can't be achieved with volatile